# Detect drive letter not being used for mapping network share

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-services, network-share

I'm writing a C++ application that is run as Windows Service (Win XP, Vista, 7, 8, servers).
My apllication uses third-patry library that maps local folder to the drive and this drive should be available in user mode (for all users). The problem occurs when user has some network share mapped to the local drive and third-party library doesn't recognize that specified drive letter as already in use.
The question is how to determine (from service application) if required drive letter is definitely available?
I'm using

```
GetLogicalDrives
QueryDosDevice
```

to determine logical devices. I've tried

```
WNetGetConnection
WNetGetUniversalName
```

to retrieve information about network share, but those functions doesn't return anything for required drive letter despite the fact that there were shares mapped to the specified drive letters.
My guess is that problem is in priveledges. Since my application run as service it can't get information about shares mapped in user mode (which seems very strange to me).
So the final question is - how to detect if specified drive letter is not used for mapping network share by any user?

Comment: Have you tried with the service running under that users' context (Login as)?

Comment: I did and application detected shares mapped using subst, but it didn't detect shares mapped using explorer's "map network drive"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in fact that there may be a difference with shares that a user can hold and shares that an admin can hold.

There is a flag in the registry that controls this:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

EnableLinkedConnections = 1 (DWord)

Here is also a [MSDN-KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937624) that explains this. Using `EnableLinkedConnections` set to 1 should fix this. Usually it is set to 1.

Background: When the UAC was invented this change was one side effect.

Comment: I set `EnableLinkedConnections` to 1, re-logged and nothing changed. Thanks for the article though.

Comment: It may be needed to restart the computer. Keep in mind that the sessions may be still split. So there are two informations. One for the user mode, one for he admin mode. What happens if you add a mapping in user mode. It should now be visible as an admin. What happens if you open a cmd.exe prompt as an admin and you press NET USE?

Comment: Well it definitely needed restart. After restart net use from administrator showed shares created by user (old and newly created). But neither WNetGetConnection, nor WNetGetUniversalName returned anything appropriate. Moreover shares mounted using subst are still not visible. Anyway, this approach is not very good since it require UAC modification which is not very appropriate on client computer..